# NDpend Variable Calculations

Tags: ndepend

Trying to use a custom NDepend variable in place of a constant and cannot work out some of the intricacies of the NDepend syntax around the `let` keyword.

One of the built in queries is:

```
warnif count > 0 from m in JustMyCode.Methods where 
  m.CyclomaticComplexity > 30 ||
  m.ILCyclomaticComplexity > 60 ||
  m.ILNestingDepth > 6
  orderby m.CyclomaticComplexity descending,
          m.ILCyclomaticComplexity descending,
          m.ILNestingDepth descending
select new { m, m.CyclomaticComplexity, 
                m.ILCyclomaticComplexity,
                m.ILNestingDepth  }
```

Whereas what I really want to do is not use a 0 constant value and base that on the codebase instead.  Something along the lines of:

```
let tenPercent = (JustMyCode.Methods.Count() / 100 * 10)
warnif count > tenPercent from m in JustMyCode.Methods where 
  m.CyclomaticComplexity > 30 ||
...
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write something like this...

```
warnif percentage > 10 
from m in Application.Methods where 
m.CyclomaticComplexity > 2
select new { m, m.CyclomaticComplexity }
```

...but this feature is kinda hidden (`percentage` keyword doesn't appear in intellisense) because it is not polished yet. The percentage base is the total number of methods (including abstract methods, third-party methods, generated methods...) and this base number is actually not configurable. Also the constant value (10 here) cannot be an expression.

[image]